# Online Backup services for Mac that work well in Australia

Tags: backup, cloud-storage, macos

I am looking for a Online Backup service like Backblaze or Crashplan **that works well in Australia**.

I have used [Crashplan](https://www.crashplan.com/en-us/) for two years and it worked well, because they have servers close to Australia. (For reasons not to be discussed here I want to move on from them though.)

With big hopes I  tried [Backblaze](https://www.backblaze.com/) but it is terrible; I guess because it's servers are all located far away in the Americas.

So I am looking for other Online Backup services with a Mac client which work well in Australia. **Anybody some good experiences?** (I saw [Acronis](https://www.acronis.com/en-au/personal/computer-backup/) but haven't tried it yet.)

Comment: Why would the location matter? I use Backblaze and it works great but I'm in the USA.

Comment: The greater physical distance makes the huge uploads unbearably slow.

Comment: the transit is very fast.  but maybe going thru different hubs slows it down.